# React imports the library incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, node-modules

The import is quite standard:

```
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from "swiper/react";
```

However, the entire project is written in JavaScript, and the import comes from `swiper-react.d.ts`.

I went to this file and commented everything out, the result did not change on the site in any way. That is, the import passed, but the contents of the file were apparently not read

Other libraries are also imported via TS files, some work and some don't, I had to forcibly delete TS files from node_modules. But it didn't work out that way with this library

What is the problem at all? Why can't React import this library?

One day he imported the library from the Vue folder altogether, and he actually Reacted

Comment: Can you share your package.json? What bundler/compiler are you using?

Comment: I use Vite + React
Package.json in too long, I can't share it here
But I use the last version of react and vite and swiper. Working in PHPStorm

Answer (score 1):

The `swiper` module was written by JavaScript and it has both JavaScript import and TypeScript import files. So you don't need to modify the contents of `swiper` module.
You can install swiper using below command.

```
npm i swiper
```

I tried it on my side and it works well.
Below is the code which I tried.

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={3}
        onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
        onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        ...
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you still have trouble, it would be related to other things.